# The Officer and the Night

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> Six men enter a building,
> Only three leave living,
>
> A police officer comes by and arrests no one,
> Pacing through the building without his gun.
>
> Obviously distraught, our officer waits,
> Pleading with heaven, he cries to the fates.
>
> Eternity passes, the night rages on,
> Running through the building, he says, "Come on."
>
> As daylight breaks, the officer droops his head in sorrow,
> Sadness in his eyes, the good man leaves, it is the morrow.

Where are these people at and what is going on?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Were they in a

> Hospital?

The initial lines of the puzzle do indicate

> A Soap Opera

Amongst the most famous ones is

> General Hospital

In general, some people taken to these types of facilities don't always survive.

> Since he was in a hospital, he would not carry his firearm while wanting to speak to these folks.

About the situation they are in:

> Given the amount of grief the officer appears to be in, I would say the three fallen members were part of his police team.  They may have taken a bullet in the line of fire and died overnight, not surviving the surgery meant to save their lives.

Comment: This is partly correct, your location is right, but the situation not quite. Why is the officer sad?

Comment: Edited the answer to address specifics in the situation they are in

Comment: That is correct. Good job!

Answer (score 7):

What happened was a

> hostage taking

Six men enter a building,
Only three leave living,

> 3 criminals took 3 person hostage, but they released the hostages

A police officer comes by and arrests no one,
Pacing through the building without his gun.

> because the police officer was a negociator and exchanged the 3 hostages for himself

Obiously distraught, our officer waits,
Pleading with heaven, he cries to the fates.

> while waiting with the criminals, he hopes not to get killed

Eternity passes, the night rages on,
Running through the building, he says, "Come on."

> in that situation every second feels like an hour, but he manages to escape the criminals, running through the corridor he tells the SWAT to intervene

As daylight breaks, the officer droops his head in sorrow,
Sadness in his eyes, the good man leaves, it is the morrow.

> unfortunatly, during the SWAT's assalut, one of them died, filling the officer with grief

Comment: Man, this is good, it might be better than the answer I had intended. But this is not the situation, nor did you mention where they were at.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like

> Three living men carried three dead men in to a funeral parlour. The police officer had a very close relationship with the three dead men and spent the night wandering the halls in grief.

This doesn't really address specifics of the lines of the riddle, though. So, probably not right?

Comment: They were all living when they entered the building. Not only that, but you didn't say where they were at either. But nice guess.

Comment: Nice edit for the location, but it's still not correct, neither the situation nor the place.

Answer (score 1):

Are you at a

> Soap opera?

Reasoning:

> The first letter of each line spell Soap Operas
>  The officer is crying because it is a soap opera
>  I still don't know how six people entered but only three exited

Comment: No, they're not in a soap opera, though this situation would make a good one in my opinion. Perhaps that clue shouldn't be taken so literally?